# Smart Contracts: Dynamically make and fill variables in Javascript by taking informations from HTML to send in MetaMask

Tags: javascript, ethereum, blockchain, smartcontracts, web3js

[image: img]

As you can see, i am working on smart contracts.

I have a parsing function that when i give an ABI/JSON it is showing up the function with is variable.

Now, i want the informations that getting out from the parsing to sending them to the MetaMask, but i don't know how is proper to get them and i need help with the source code.

I want to have in one variable the function type as it is shown at the picture with the arrow.

And i want making variables name with the names that are shown (_startTime as an example) with the value from the input box that the user will give.

Comment: Hi people,
I think that i have to run a javascript for loop in my div where the viarables value is and put them in an array, it would be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Metamask is a plugin used to execute the transaction. You can also send data with the transaction to the Metamask. To initiate the transaction first you have to login into the Metamask. Later you have to select the Network in the metamask and use Web3 wrapper to execute the transaction. I did that using Truffle and running local blockchain on my PC.